# Is there way to programmatically determine if a private key is in encoded in DER or PEM?

Tags: javascript, private-key

I was wondering if there is a way in javascript to determine if a key is encoded in DER or PEM without using the file extension (because it could  be misleading)?

Comment: Try decrypting the key using a library similar to https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa

If you don't get any error then its encoded in the decrypted format.

Comment: How are you accessing the file?

Answer (score 1):

If simplify: DER is binary key data, PEM is base64 encoded DER + header like '-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'. So, you can check, if you file starts with something like '-----BEGIN' it most likely PEM key.